# Applying function to list of data frames

Tags: r, function, purrr, tilde

I have a large list of data frames that all contain the same column headings that I would like to apply the same function with multiple arguments to.

Example list of 2 data frames :

```
df<- data.frame(Epoch = c(99,126,136,148,150,200,228,247,268,269,285,285,294,308,309,319,320,324,326,337,338,352,353,380,382,418,419,424,431,437,440,447,449,470,515,548,550,550,561,589,590,596,598,603,612,616,623,626,633,655,663,668,682,687,704,708,717,730,744,752,771,794,810,811,816,819,825,832,832,841,847,851,853,868,871,881,893,915,918,922,935,943),
                Event = c( "hypopnea","auto_trig","double_trig","auto_trig","double_trig"   , "double_trig" ,"hypopnea" ,"hypopnea","auto_trig" ,"double_trig","auto_trig","double_trig"  , "double_trig" ,"auto_trig", "double_trig","auto_trig", "double_trig","auto_trig", "double_trig" , "double_trig", "hypopnea","hypopnea" ,"double_trig","double_trig","hypopnea", "double_trig" ,"hypopnea" , "double_trig", "high_leak", "auto_trig", "double_trig", "auto_trig" ,"double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "hypopnea", "auto_trig",  "double_trig",  "hypopnea",  "double_trig", "auto_trig",    "double_trig", "auto_trig","double_trig","double_trig","auto_trig", "auto_trig","hypopnea",    "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "auto_trig", "double_trig","auto_trig", "hypopnea" , "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "ineffective_eff", "ineffective_eff", "double_trig", "double_trig", "high_leak", "double_trig",  "hypopnea", "auto_trig", "hypopnea",        "double_trig", "high_leak", "double_trig", "high_leak", "auto_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig",   "double_trig", "double_trig", "auto_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig", "double_trig"))

df2<- data.frame(Epoch = c(98,99,126,135,141,181,183,200,236,247,257,284,308,353,353,354,380,382,418,418,431,561,733,751,841,851),
                 Event = c("double_trig", "hypopnea", "auto_trig", "hypopnea", "hypopnea", "double_trig", "hypopnea", "double_trig", "hypopnea", "hypopnea", "hypopnea", "double_trig", "hypopnea", "double_trig", "hypopnea", "double_trig", "hypopnea", "high_leak", "hypopnea", "hypopnea", "ineffective_eff", "high_leak", "high_leak", "double_trig", "double_trig", "ineffective_eff"))

List1<- list(df, df2)
```

The components of the function that I would like to apply to the list of data frames (with an example on an individual data frame):

```
df3<- data.frame(Section = seq(1, max(df$Epoch/10+1), by = 1),
                Epoch5 = seq(1, max(df$Epoch), by =10),
                Epoch51 =seq(11, max(df$Epoch)+10, by = 10))

sp <- split(df$Epoch, df$Event)
nms <- names(sp)
E <- c(df3$Epoch5, max(df3$Epoch51))

df3 <- df3 |>
  cbind(
    sapply(nms, \(i) {
      sec <- findInterval(sp[[i]], E)
      df3$Section %in% sec |> as.integer()
    })
  )

rm(sp, nms, E)
```

I've tried using combinations of ".," or "~" as placeholders for the "df" with no success (usually error message saying "Epoch" or "Event" does not exist") when I've tried to translate the above code into a function which is then applied to the list of data frames using purrr::map().  Would someone be able to show me what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi AR459! Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: "the function" <- which function?

Comment: Hi Mark, a custom function that is able to be applied to any data frame which contains the column "Epoch" and "Event"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're wanting something like this:

```
processdf <- function(df) {
    df3<- data.frame(Section = seq(1, max(df$Epoch/10+1), by = 1),
                Epoch5 = seq(1, max(df$Epoch), by =10),
                Epoch51 =seq(11, max(df$Epoch)+10, by = 10))

    sp <- split(df$Epoch, df$Event)
    nms <- names(sp)
    E <- c(df3$Epoch5, max(df3$Epoch51))

    df3 |>
    cbind(
        sapply(nms, \(i) {
        sec <- findInterval(sp[[i]], E)
        df3$Section %in% sec |> as.integer()
        })
    )
}

lapply(List1, processdf)
```

Comment: When I run this code, it looks as though it is applying the data from one data frame (df) to all of the other data frames in the list.  But as each data frame contains different types of events, and a different number of epochs, I am having difficulty writing the code to make each of the "df$Epoch" etc. generalisable for the individual data frame in the list.  So, for df2 listed  in the example above, I would want the code to use Section = seq(1, max(df2$Epoch/10+1, by =1) rather than Section = seq(1, max(df$Epoch/10+1), by = 1).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @AR459 the term `df` in `function(df)` is just a "pronoun" to represent any data frame that is passed into function `processdf`. It is *not* aimed at the `df` inside `List1`. If you mess up the object names, you could replace all the "df" in `processdf` with another term, e.g. `x`.